# Number of elements in $\mathbb{Z}_p[x]/(f(x)).$

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory

Let $f\in\mathbb{Z}_p[x]$, and define $N(f)$ to be the number of elements in $\mathbb{Z}_p[x]/(f(x)).$ Show that $N(fg)=N(f)N(g)$. Define $\phi(f)$. Then, show that $\phi(\pi^m)=N(\pi)^m-N(\pi)^{m-1}$ for any prime $\pi\in\mathbb{Z}_p[x]$. Is $\phi$ multiplicative?

Comment: What is your definition of $\phi(f)$?

Comment: @user2566092 I think it's Euler's totient function (one way of defining it is the number of units in $\mathbb Z_p[x]/(f(x))$).

Comment: Is $\mathbb{Z}_p$ defined as $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$?

Comment: I have an approach using category theory. If anybody wants to see it, I will type it using a diagram and all.

Comment: I'm curious to see the proof :)

Comment: @KarlKronenfeld: I'd like to see it too. Also, please verify if my answer and the comment under it are correct if possible.

Comment: $\mathbb{Z}_p$ is awkward notation here, because it's commonly used in number theory to denote the $p$-adic integers. $\mathbb{F}_p$ is unambiguous.

Comment: I was pulling a Fermat there. I missed an important detail.

Comment: It is a well-known result that if $f$ is a polynomial over an arbitrary field $K$ (or just commutative ring, when the leading coefficient of $f$ is a unit), of degree $n$, then $K[x]/(f)$ is free over $K$ with basis $1,x,\dotsc,x^{n-1}$. From this everything follows.

Answer (score 1):

HINT: OK. Suppose that $\deg(f)=n$. What can you say about the number of elements in $\mathbb{Z}_p[x]/(f(x))$?

By using Euclid's division algorithm on $\mathbb{Z}_p[x]$ (I'm assuming that $p$ is prime, so $\mathbb{Z}_p$ is a field) you can see that for any polynomial $g(x)$ in $\mathbb{Z}_p[x]/(f(x))$ we can write:

$g(x) = f(x)\cdot q(x) + r(x)$ where $\deg(r(x)) < \deg(f(x))$.

So, all polynomials in $\mathbb{Z}_p[x]/(f(x))$ has a representative with degree less than $n=\deg(f(x))$. Since $\{1,x,\cdots, x^{n-1}\}$ is a basis for all polynomials of degree less than $n$ by definition every such polynomial is a linear combination of $a_0\cdot 1 + a_1 \cdot x + \cdots + a_{n-1} \cdot x^{n-1}$ where $a_i \in \mathbb{Z}_p$. Simple counting shows that there are $p^n$ such linear combinations.

Since $\mathbb{Z}_p$ is a field, we know that $\deg(fg)=\deg(f)+\deg(g)$.

But:
 $$N(fg)=p^{\deg(fg)}=p^{\deg(f)+\deg(g)}=p^{\deg{f}}\cdot p^{\deg{g}} = N(f) \cdot N(g)$$

Now define $\varphi(f)$ to be the number of polynomials that are not zero-divisors in $\bar{f} \in \mathbb{Z}_p[x]/(f(x))$.

If $\pi$ is an irreducible polynomial in $\mathbb{Z}_p[x]$ then $\varphi(\pi)=N(\pi)-1$ because $\mathbb{Z}_p[x]/(\pi(x))$ will be a field and every non-zero element in it is a unit and hence no element excluding zero could be a zero divisor.

Now you can use the same logic for $\pi^m$. The idea is that if you want to see how many polynomials are not zero divisors in $\mathbb{Z}_p[x]/(\pi^m)$ you can count the number of elements that are not nilpotent in there. Can you take care of the rest from here?

To study if $\varphi(f)$ is multiplicative in the number theoretic sense of the word, suppose that $\gcd(f,g)=1$. Then $(f)+(g)=(\gcd(f,g))=(1)$. By using Chinese Remainder Theorem for commutative rings we now can see:

$$\mathbb{Z}_p[x]/(fg) \cong \mathbb{Z}_p[x]/(f) \oplus \mathbb{Z}_p[x]/(g)$$

Now you should count the number of elements that are not zero-divisors in $\mathbb{Z}_p[x]/(f) \oplus \mathbb{Z}_p[x]/(g)$.

Comment: Don't you mean $\varphi(\pi) = N(\pi)-1$ because $\mathbb{Z}_p[x]/\pi$ is a field?

Comment: I don't know, I have edited my post several times from then anytime I advanced my chain of thoughts further, so if I had written something else back then that was wrong because surely $\mathbb{Z}_p[x]/(\pi(x))$ is the correct one. Can you see why we have to count non-nilpotent elements in $\mathbb{Z}_p[x]/(\pi^m(x))$ to find $\varphi(\pi^m)$?

Comment: Also, how about showing that $\varphi$ is multiplicative?

Comment: Yes I see how to compute $\varphi(\pi^m)$ now, thank you.

Comment: @ThomasR.: Use Chinese remainder theorem to see that if we mod out by $fg$ when $\gcd(f,g)=1$ then the quotient ring will be isomorphic to $R/(f)$ direct sum with $R/(g)$. This is what is in my head, I haven't done the details yet. But it seems like the most fruitful idea in my head now. Is my idea clear for computing the case when $\gcd(f,g)=1$?

Comment: @ThomasR.: Out of curiosity, would you tell me where you found this problem?

Comment: @Hurkyl: Yes, that's true. I changed my definition to this: $\varphi(f)$ = number of zero-divisors in the quotient ring $\mathbb{Z}_p/(f(x))$. Is it true now? I wrote everything spontaneously, so I have committed some mistakes that need to be fixed I guess.